# Kotlin when with multiple values not working when value is an android view

Tags: android, kotlin

I implemented a function that is used in anko's apply recursively:

```
fun applyTemplateViewStyles(view: View) {
    when(view) {
        is EditText, TextView -> {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

And I receive an error saying that "Function invocation 'TextView(...)' expected"

Since I can write an when with a clause like is 0, 1, why I can't do the same with an Android View?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You're missing the other `is`:

```
fun applyTemplateViewStyles(view: View) {
    when(view) {
        is EditText, is TextView -> {
            println("view is either EditText or TextView")
        }
        else -> {
            println("view is something else")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is quite intuitive. I love Kotlin

Comment: I thought this is quite unintuitive. Intuitive would have been `is A, B -> ...`

Comment: When matching a sealed class though, I ran into a problem. Say, sealed class Bla is used like this: `Yes(val index: Int): Bla()` and `No(val index: Int): Bla()`. When matching: `when (blaValue) { is Yes, is No -> println("Can't access data class value") }` works but there is not automatic casting, although it's of the same type in both cases. In Swift the same thing works: `switch blaValue { case .yes(let index), .no(let index): print("Value is accessible") }`

Comment: As at Jan 2020 with Kotlin 1.3.50, `is` is not required anymore.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this, you just didn't get the syntax right. The following works for handling multiple types under one branch of `when`:

```
when(view) {
    is EditText, is TextView -> {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: but unfortunately automatic casting is not working in this case :-(

Comment: @Angelina that is expected as there are two types of values coming in.

Answer (score 11):

In case of multiple text option handling
you can use comma

```
when(option) { //option is string
    "type A","type B" -> {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use comma-separated to handle multiple options for the same execution.

```
{ 
view ->
   when(view.id) {
       homeView.tv_new_dealer_rank_to_achieve.id,
       homeView.tv_sales_rank_to_achieve.id,
       homeView.tv_payment_rank_to_achieve.id,
       homeView.tv_bill_dealer_rank_to_achieve.id -> {
           homePresenter.reDirectToFragment(10)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the tricky part of the question was the usage of the `is` operator. I think your example is besides the point.